# Group by Sum in Excel

Tags: excel, sum, grouping

Let's assume that I have the following table in Excel

```
A     B
Item  quantity_sold
A     3
A     4
A     1
B     5
B     2
D     12
C     3
C     7
C     8
```

and I need to sum up quantity_sold grouped by Item and print the results on the adjacent column only once per group, similar to the following

```
A     B                 C   
Item  quantity_sold    SUM_by_item_type
A     3                 8
A     4
A     1
B     5                 7
B     2
D     12                12
C     3                 18
C     7
C     8
```

Is there any way I can achieve this without using Pivot Tables?

[image]

Comment: What do you have against pivot tables?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this formula in C2 copied down

`=IF(A2=A1,"",SUMIF(A:A,A2,B:B))`

That will give you a sum on the first row of each group - other rows are left blank

Comment: The formula above resulted in empty cell. No answers returned. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Ahmedov, Barry's formula works if you have a title row (as in your examples. If you don't have a title row, as you show in your screenshot, then the formula in C1 would be `=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)>1,"",SUMIF(A:A,A1,B:B))` and that can be copied down as before

Comment: It may depend on regional settings, e.g. some European countries require semi-colons in place of commas, e.g. `=IF(A2=A1;"";SUMIF(A:A;A2;B:B))`

Comment: Oh that is probably it, as "," is decimal delimiter. Thank you!

Comment: For me, it worked when I have title row and I changed "," to ";"

Comment: I tried this but all I am getting is 0 in the output. I have some blank values in the column which I want to sum. Is it because of that?

Answer (score 4):

I'd create a smaller table alongside (or on a different sheet) and use

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"A",B:B)
```

where...

```
=SUMIF(different-item-range,"what you're looking for",things-to-add-together)
```

`=SUMIF` is all explained here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/sumif-function-HP010062465.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Subtotal feature:

1. Click the Data tab in Excel's ribbon toolbar
2. Click the Sort button and sort by your category column
3. Click the Subtotal button and fill in the dialog as appropriate,
   then click OK

Video example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OBj30n_x5aQ