# Sum column B until there is any change in column A

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a formula that does a sum of column B until there is any change in column A. 
E.g.

```
    Col A   Col B

1     X       2
2     X       1
3     X       0
4     X       2
5     Y       1
```

Starting at the point of A1, this would then show the sum of 5. Column A in this situation would always be sorted (X, followed by Y, followed by Z etc.)

Comment: Is you A column always going to be sorted?

Comment: @BruceWayne    I've edited the original question, yes it would always be sorted.

Comment: Another way of thinking about @BruceWayne's question is, does the order matter (I.e. If column A goes back to x do you want a separate sum) or do you just want a frequency table, where all instances of column A sum the values in column B

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870378/group-by-sum-in-excel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With data in cols **A** and **B**, in **C2** enter:

=IF(A3<>A2,SUM($B$2:B2)-SUM($C$1:C1),"")

and copy down:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

This approach requires:

1. the tags in column **A** must be sorted into groups
2. row #1 is unused for data

Comment: Should clarify that column A must be sorted (although he specifies this in the Q, it is still important to note)

Comment: @Chrismas007  Done as you suggest!!

Comment: @Chrismas007  I appreciate both your upvote and your suggestion for improving the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this question is long ago answered, but I'd like to share my solution;

Like @Gary's Student showed, i suggest a similar way. You could also go with a `IF` + `SUMIF`

With data in cols **A** and **B**, in **C2** enter:

```
=IF(A2<>A3,SUMIF(A:A,A2,B:B),"")
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5HDB.png)

OBS.: The data needs to be sorted before using the formula.

I hope it help other people!