# Need help combining and adding strings in Excel

Tags: excel, ms-office, formula, excel-2016

I have a list of items in one column and a total number in another column. I need to combine every instance an item appears in `column A` and the amounts in `column B`.  I also need it to sort by highest number first on its own if possible. Here is an example of what I mean.

`Column A & B` is my list, `Column D & E` is what I want the results to look like:

[image: Excel Example]

Can anyone help out?  I've racked my brains for days and cant seem to get it to work.  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group by Sum in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870378/group-by-sum-in-excel)

Answer (score 1):

This is what pivot tables do...

- Create a pivot table  Image below.

  - place cursor in D2
  - Menu - Insert
  - Tables - Pivot table
  - Select range of data
  - fill out fields on right as in image. (I had A on line 2 = 3 so my total said 14 and didn't refresh before I took the screen capture)
  - right click on a value in the sum of total column and click sort from popup and select largest to smallest.

[image]